# Where to define command in nagios

Tags: nagios, centos5, nrpe

I want to define new command in nagios for remote host but i can't find out where should i write this thing

```
define command   {


}
```

on remote host i have only this file

```
 vim /usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg
```

Should i write that in above file or i have to write that on nagios host not on remote computer

There is no commands.cfg file on my remote host

Comment: You really need to learn to read documentation. Start here: http://www.nagios.org/documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which Nagios packages do you have installed?  On my CentOS 5.4 boxes, the Nagios config is in `/etc/nagios`.  Take a look there.  The filename is `/etc/nagios/nagios.cfg`

*Edit*

On the remote side, you need an entry in the `nrpe.cfg` that looks like `command[something]=/some/path/to/command/binary`.  Then, on the Nagios host, you do your `define service { }`.  The important part is that the command to run is going to look like `check_nrpe!something`, where `something` is the same as the one in `nrpe.cfg`.

Comment: i have nagios 3.2. and i am talking bout remote machine. the only cfg file i have is 

/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg

I am taking about NRPE plugin

Comment: Actually i have that nagios.cfg but that is on host where nagios monitoring system is installed. i am talking about where nagios plugin and NRPE plugin is installed. where do i have to define command and in which file. EITHER on host or remote computer

Comment: Oh, ok.  You need to have two parts for NRPE to work.  I'll update my answer with it so I can get some formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are configuring to monitor a remote host, you will have to add a command in your **nrpe.cfg** found at `/usr/local/nagios/etc/`.

This command should be on the remote host. The sample commands that are already defined are :

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_users

/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_load

/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_hda1

/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_total_procs

/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H localhost -c check_zombie_procs
```

Then adding the command definition to the any of the config file that you have specified in **nagios.cfg**

```
define command{
command_name check_nrpe
command_line $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

And finally your host and service

Correct me if i am wrong. I am not sure if nagios would reset the settings back to default for **commands.cfg**.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the commands in the file `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg` on the nagios host. Open that file and you should see examples for the syntax there.